# For which integers $n$ will $2n^2+1$ be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I see that for $n^2 = 0, 4, 144, 4900, 166464$, etc. we get a perfect square, but is it possible to obtain an analytical solution?

Comment: This is [A084703](https://oeis.org/A084703)

Comment: Try looking up Pell's equation. You are interested in the Diophantine equation $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$.

Comment: To be clear:  the OEIS sequence, and your partial sequence assumes that *both* $n, 2n^2+1$ are perfect squares.  That's not clear from what you write, however.

Comment: Please edit your question. Your numbers belong to a sequence of squares for which $2n+1$, not $2n^2+1$, is a square.

Comment: As indicated by the comment of @user42308, you want the complete (infinite) list of positive integer solutions $~(x,y)~$ such that $~x^2 - 2y^2 = 1.~$  These solutions may be expressed as $~(x,y) = (P_k,Q_k) ~: k,P_k,Q_k \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ where $~(P_k,Q_k)~$ is defined by $$P_k + Q_k\sqrt{2} = \left[ ~3 + 2\sqrt{2} ~\right]^k.$$

Comment: For your sequence to be correct, you need to either replace $2n^2+1$ with $2n+1$ or replace the $n$ values with their square roots ($0, 2, 12, 70, 408, ...$), which form the OEIS sequence [A001542](https://oeis.org/A001542).

Comment: $2(4)^2+1=33$ is not a perfect square

Comment: Any reason for writing $n^2 = 0, 4, 144, 4900, 166464$ instead of $n = 0, 2, 12, 70, 408$?

Comment: If not assuming that $n$ itself is a perfect square, this is [A001542](https://oeis.org/A001542).